# Getting nodes OSMIDs using Valhalla locate

Tags: python, openstreetmap, map-matching, valhalla

I need to map-match my nodes to OSMID ways using Valhalla's 'locate' API. It works fine except one thing: it counts the 'percent_along' value, but doesn't mention which node it counts this value from (see the first picture). I tried to modify my query so 'verbose' is True. However, the result it gives is not from the area I'm working with, the node with such id is located in Indonesia, but I work with data from Russia.

[image: This is when I use 'verbose' = False][image: This is when I use 'verbose' = True]

Comment: Kindly paste the code here rather adding a screenshot so that it can be reproduced.